# What are the Contents of /proc/vmcore

Tags: linux-kernel, coredump

When the Kernel panics, it generates the /proc/vmcore file.  Later we could use the makedumpfile utility to generate coredump using this vmcore file.

What are the contents of this vmcore file?

Does it contain Kernel Memory Region like Stack Area, Heap Area, Code Area and Constants?

Does it also contains Process specific Information ? Process Memory Region , etc., ?

Please share some information/links to understand the contains of vmcore and how to optimize or reduce the Kernel Core Dump Size.

Comment: `/proc/vmcore` is not documented in [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Answer (score 2):

Mr. Anderson has kindly provided the following info.  I am posting on his behalf

> When the Kernel panics, it generates the /proc/vmcore file. Later we
>   could  use the makedumpfile utility to generate coredump using this
>   vmcore file.
>
> What are the contents of this vmcore file?
>
> Does it contain Kernel Memory Region like Stack Area, Heap Area, Code
>   Area  and Constants?

/proc/vmcore is an ELF-format core file which contains all of the physical memory
utilized by the crashed kernel.

> Does it also contains Process specific Information ? Process Memory Region
>   , etc., ?

It contains NT_PRSTATUS ELF notes which contain information for the process
that was actively running on each cpu when the system crashed.  It also contains
a VMCOREINFO note that is specific to kdump, which contains information
about the crashed kernel that is used by makedumpfile and the crash utility.

> Please share some information/links to understand the contains of vmcore
>   and how to optimize or reduce the Kernel Core Dump Size.

That is the whole purpose of makedumpfile(8).  Instead of having to utilize
a huge dumpfile that is the size of the crashed kernel's memory, it allows
you to both (1) compress the /proc/vmcore contents, and (2) to filter out
pages that are typically unnecessary for crash analysis, e.g., user-space
pages, free pages, zero-filled pages, and page cache pages.

Dave